# Where to put await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, io

I'd like to learn if there is a right answer of where to wait for async operations. If this is a topic with depth I'm also happy to receive articles or programming-terms to read up on.

Let's say we have a slow async operation, perhaps reading a large file:

```
const resolver = (x) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(x)}, 500)
  })
}
```

I can see two ways to use `resolver`:

```
const one = async () => {
  const result = await resolver('foo')
  console.log(result)
}

const two = async () => {
  const result = resolver('foo')
  console.log(await result)
}
```

(Note the differently placed `await` keyword)

In `one` we immediately wait, and this is the pattern I've been exposed to. I think it's the normal and expected pattern?

But should that line really wait for the result? It doesn't **really** need it resolved, right? `result` is only really consumed on the next line.. so why not wait there, as `two` illustrates?

There's obviously no gain in clarity for this trivial example, but in a larger function with multiple awaits and multiple consumers of the asynchronous result, I can maybe see it will be clearer to have the `await` colocated where it is actually required, rather than an upfront wait just because later code needs it.

Any right answers? Or thoughts? And if this is all a giant waste of worry then I'm happy to learn of that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right. In larger pieces of code, where you put await matters.

The following is an example of how the two styles lead to completely different interpretations:

```
// Example 1 - serial async operations

async function () {
    var a = await foo();
    var b = await bar();

    console.log(a+b);
}
```

Assuming that `foo` and `bar` each takes one second to return results, the above code will take roughly two seconds to execute.

```
// Example 2 - parallel async operations

async function () {
    var a = foo();
    var b = bar();

    var aa = await a;
    var bb = await b;
    console.log(aa+bb);
}
```

Making the same assumptions as the first example, the above code would take roughly one second to execute because `bar` will be executed in parallel without waiting for `foo` to complete.